# Отображение карты при разных системах координат OSM

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson, ol3

Я так понял OSM изначально может работать только с EPSG:3857, но данные в geojson хранятся в EPSG:4326.

```
var geojsonObject = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [[40, 52.70], [116.20, 70]]
      }
    }
  ]
};

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
});

var rasterLayer  = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        center: [37.61, 55.75],
        zoom: 4
    })
});
```

В таком случае карта отображается нормально, но линия рисуется в координатах [0, 0] [image: EPSG:3857]

Если же поменять проекцию на EPSG:4326

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        center: [37.61, 55.75],
        zoom: 4
    })
});
```

карта начинает жутко лагать, долго подгружаться и верхняя часть растянута, но зато правильно рисуется линия
[image: EPSG:4326]

Подскажите, как правильно работать с geojson в 4326
PS много постов видел про использование *ol.source.GeoJSON*, но у меня выдает ошибку *ol.source.GeoJSON is not a constructor*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет [ol.source.GeoJSON](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.GeoJSON) - смотрите в документации.

Могу предложить несколько вариантов работы с геометрией в проекции отличной от карты:

1. [Перепроецирование](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.proj.html#.transform) координат перед созданием объектов: `ol.proj.transform`
2. [Перепроецирование](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Geometry.html#transform) перед добавлением в слой: `geomFeature.transform`
3. [Перепроецирование](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#addFeature) по событию добавления в слой: `srcVector.on('addfeature'`

**PS**
Учитесь пользоваться документацией ;)

Ваш пример достаточно записать так:

```js
var geojsonObject = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [[40, 52.70], [116.20, 70]]
            }
        }
    ]
};

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: ( new ol.format.GeoJSON() ).readFeatures( geojsonObject ).map(
        function( feature ) {
            console.log( feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0] );
            feature.getGeometry().transform( 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857' );
            console.log( feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0] );
            return feature;
        }
    )
});
```

```html
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/build/ol.js"></script>
```

Вывод в консоль добавлен для наглядности.